# Is there a way to develop a custom Git comparison extension?

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook

Consider the *.ipynb file extension. This is a text file formatted for use as a [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/).

`git diff` for these files is impossible to decipher. Merging operations are able to make changes that break the notebook format.

Is there a way to write a plugin or extension for Git which provides custom diffing and merging logic based on file extension?

Comment: I found a few existing questions which might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9154110/157957 https://stackoverflow.com/q/35606909/157957 https://stackoverflow.com/q/20069976/157957

Comment: https://www.wrighters.io/jupytext-notebooks-as-markdown-or-python/

Comment: Thanks for the links, after reading through the Q/A and exploring, I found this: https://github.com/Praqma/git-merge-driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, using [Git filters](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)

There are also a few tools that do this for Jupyter Notebooks, for example [nbdime](https://nbdime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vcs.html) or [nbstripout](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout), both support Git filters.

Comment: Thank you! Git filters looks like the way to go. Where is the interface documented? What are the requirements for my own executable that acts as a diff and merge filter?

Comment: So it looks like this method is for diff only. There appears to be no solution for merge. Here the documentation is pointed to but contains no further details regarding output formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35607744/2580891

Comment: This project has built a "merge driver". Wonder if it can be adapted for generic use: https://nbdime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vcs.html#merge-driver

Comment: Aha: https://github.com/Praqma/git-merge-driver